# Button with url

Tags: html, url, redirect, button

I wanna switch this code:

```
<a href="selectare_gen.php" target="continut">Inapoi</a>
```

With a button. I want a button who redirect to ”selectare_gen.php”
I tried:

```
<button onclick="location.href='selectare_gen.php'">Inapoi</button>
```

But all it does is refreshing the current page..

Comment: I dont wanna use css if it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<button type="reset" onclick="location.href='selectare_gen.php'">
    Inapoi
</button>
```

The `type="reset"` is a workaround to prevent the browser from interpreting the button as a form element which causes the reload.

Comment: Type `button` would be a better solution as it "[Does nothing](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)". No need for a workaround. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link over here. It should answer your question.

[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers think that the `<button>` tag will cause a submit that's why it's appearing to just refresh the page.  If you use an input type="button" it wouldn't have this effect:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location='selectare_gen.php';" value="Inapoi" />
```

Comment: The reason why many browsers think that, is because "[The missing value default is the Submit Button state.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)".